# Divide values in one column by the total number of lines in the file

Tags: awk

I have several data files in this format:

```
orange 25 high
red 23 low
blue 20 low
green 10 high
```

I would like to divide column 2 by the total number of lines in the file.
I've tried this:

```
awk '{$2=$2/NR}1'
```

but the output divides the first row by 1, the second by 2 etc.  I want each row divided by the total number of lines in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Get the number of lines first, and pass that to `awk`.

```
lines=$(wc -l < filename)
awk -v "lines=$lines" '{ $2 /= lines }1' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` and harness fact that `NR` is total number of rows inside `END`. Let file.txt content be

```
orange 25 high
red 23 low
blue 20 low
green 10 high
```

then

```
awk '{arr[NR]=$2}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i+=1){print arr[i]/NR}}' file.txt
```

output

```
6.25
5.75
5
2.5
```

Explanation: During processing line I store value from 2nd column (`$2`) in associative array `arr` using current line number (`NR`) as key. After this done I use `for` loop to process `arr` keeping order. As I noted `NR` inside `END` is total number of rows. Note: this solution assumes you have enough memory to keep whole 2nd column in it.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*